# is oops is the solution to improve php security?

Tags: database, scripting, server-side

now we are working in one project.in that project we choosed HTML5 and CSS3 designed. but still we have confuse on server side scripting, whether php,ruby,python,scala,and more and more..our requirements is nothing but

1. SERVER SCRIPTING LANGUAGE:our server side scripting language is secure and more helpfull(ease of development,security,maintenance)  in anystage. can you please suggest me which is good at present(21-10-10)? sorry if this question is make argument...
2. and can you say which is current trend in web development language...not ask about which language...but which trend(first functional programming to  oops concepts...is still oops concepts or we switched to any recent trend? )
3. and i heard by using  proper oops class structure with any language we can enhance security? is it true?
   i searched lot and lot more than 1 week. but still confuse...
4. DATABASE: still confuse on which data base is best for us?

sorry to everyone if my question make hurt or make more discussion? and thanks to everyone...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complexity of applications, performance requirements, target audience (corporate intranet, internet,...) and budget.

If you can give more details on these then you might get a better suited answer and not a very general one (like this)

And more importantly in which technology you and your team are comfortable with. A Java project and PHP project's success, in completion and performance is more on the team's experience and expertise than on the language itself, to a great extent.

See also these questions: [(php vs python) scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588617/php-vs-python-scalability), [PHP and Java performance and scalability comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975691/php-vs-java-performance-and-scalability-comparison), and [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/09/01.html) by Joel.

Ok, you asked about security:

It is the application architecture and code that decides security at the end of the day, not the language itself.
OOP is a nice paragdim to code, makes developemnt and maintenance (arguably)easier, but end of the day, it is how you implement it, what your architecture is, and how good you coding practices are.

Answer (score 0):

OOP alone will not make your site secure.  Nor will the use of any particular language or OS or framework.  Only good practices will help you, and most of those apply regardless of paradigm, language, or platform.

As for language popularity, PHP, Python, and Ruby (on Rails) seem pretty popular.  As do .net languages, particularly C#.  Don't mistake "popular" for "good" or *especially* "secure", though -- you *need* to evaluate the languages for yourself, and don't trust what some random geek on the intarwebz tells you, as we're not the ones who'll have to build stuff with it.  And above all, *follow the best practices for the language/framework you choose*, or any benefits it claims to offer will likely be null and void.

Comment: Nit-picking a bit here but Ruby on Rails isn't a language!

Comment: No, but Ruby is.  And Rails is so commonly used with it, that when people build a site with Ruby, the "on Rails" part is almost a given.  Ruby without Rails isn't nearly as common for web apps, as far as i've seen.